# Community manim installation issue

Tags: python, installation, manim

I've installed the community manim edition according to the instructions.  I already had previously installed latex, ffmpeg, and everything else that is needed.  Now, while I think I've installed things correctly, I'm very confused about something.  If I type `manim scene.py SquareToCircle -p -ql`, as the installation instructions state, I get the error message `There are no scenes inside that module`.  However, if I type `python -m manim scene.py SquareToCircle -p -ql`, then it works as expected.  Any thoughts as to what's going on?  (And if it's not obvious, I am a novice programmer.)

Addition: Although I get an error when trying to run `manim scene.py SquareToCircle -p -ql` from the command line, it will work within a Jupyter notebook using the magic command `%%manim SquareToCircle -p -ql` (after first running `import jupyter_manim` and then copying the `SquareToCircle` code into the Jupyter code cell).  This seems surprising to me and is perhaps a clue.

Comment: One of them mentions `example.py`, one of them mentions `scene.py`.  Which is it?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo.  Both should be either `example.py` or `scene.py`.  I have tried many different files and the result is always the same.

Comment: By the way, I've been trying to dig into this issue, and I now believe it is somehow related to virtual environments.  I suspect that I have installed things in different virtual environments without realizing it, but I'm still not completely sure.